# Labeling xAxis in ios barchart 3.0

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I am trying to put labels in barchart using ios-chart 3.0 with no success. My labels are dinamically showed, are no fixed as months.

```
let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "animals")
let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: animalsArray, dataSet: chartDataSet)
```

The last line shows "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'BarChartData' with an argument list of type '(xVals: [String], dataSet: BarChartDataSet)'"

Answer (score 2):

I struggled a bit with this problem too. If I understand it correctly, starting with iOS-Charts 3.0, you can't pass x and y values at the same time, so most tutorials you find online, written for version 2.x, point you in the wrong direction (you can't use `BarChartData(xVals: dataSet:)` anymore).

On top of that, the fact that the documentation is Android-only, and that the sample code uses cryptic variable names, doesn't help a beginner like me figure this out from the sample project, but I guess I did, since now I'm able to have custom Strings as labels. Here's how:

1. Conform your class to the `IAxisValueFormatter` protocol:

   `class ChartsViewController : UIViewController, IAxisValueFormatter {//...}`

---

2. Add a property to your class for the string labels, and initialize it (either hard-coding its values as in the following example, or by setting them in your `viewDidLoad:`):

   `var labelStrings : Array<String> = ["these", "will", "be", "your", "labels"]`

---

3. Implement the required `stringForValue:` method of `IAxisValueFormatter`:

   `func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
       return labelStrings[Int(value) % labelStrings.count]}`

---

4. In your custom "configure chart" method create an XAxis object, set its valueFormatter to self (so the `stringForValue:` above is called) and set the chartView.valueFormatter equal as the Axis.valueFormatter:

   `let xAxis = XAxis()
    xAxis.valueFormatter = self
    barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xAxis.valueFormatter`

---

With the points above, you got the custom labels on the X axis, but of course you still have to set the values for Y; just in case someone else comes here for an answer in the future, here's the code to set those values too:

```
let yValues = myArrayOfCustomValues.enumerated().map { index, element -> BarChartDataEntry in
    return BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: element)
}

let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: yValues, label: "If you want a label; you can also pass nil")

let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

barChartView.data = chartData
```